# How to get process Id of certain process in C

Tags: c, windows-7, driver, wdk

I am trying to create a driver in Windows 7 32 bit.

I am writing the driver in C. In the driver code I am trying to get the process id of `notepad.exe`.

I don't know how to get the id of that process, if I use `GetProcessesByName`
I get errors like `PROCESS undeclared identifier`.

Comment: check this out, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683215(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: printf("My process ID : %d\n", getpid());
 printf("My parent's ID: %d\n", getppid()); i dont know if you mean this...

Comment: How did you start the instance of `notepad.exe`?

Comment: THe instance of notepad.exe have to be started as usual only.

Comment: I want the steps of finding PID by giving process name alone.

Comment: @darkendemon In case there are more than one instance of notepad running, which pid do you want?

Comment: I need to get all PID of the instances

Comment: ZwQuerySystemInformation\NtQuerySystemInformation function helps you.

Comment: I googled about ZwQuerySystemInformation\NtQuerySystemInformation .I think these requires handle of the process .I need to find  PID just by giving process name alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CreateToolhelp32Snapshot and associated functions are what you need.  Example code for using these functions can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686701%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Note that the PROCESSENTRY32 struct contains the EXE file name, so you're looking for "notepad.exe".  You probably should get the full path as described in the link and make sure it's in the \windows\system directory.